# Referential integrity for invoice and task tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am having trouble figuring out how to design a database for an invoicing system. I want to have an invoice table and an tasks table. I want a record in the invoices table to be able to have a variable amount of tasks associated with it but also keep referential integrity so that a task cannot be added that does not exist on the tasks table.

So far I have come up with a task_id1, task_id2, etc...  fields on the invoices table that are foreign keys to the task_id field in the tasks table but it feels limiting in the number of tasks that can be put on one invoice.

Alternatively the invoices table could have a comma separated list of task_id's that would allow for a variable amount of tasks per invoice but I cant figure out how to create the foreign key if the column types are not the same. (Plus this feels a little sloppy).

Im sure there is an easy answer I am not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far I have come up with a task_id1, task_id2, etc... fields on the
> invoices table that are foreign keys to the task_id field
>
> Alternatively the invoices table could have a comma separated list of
> task_id's that would allow for a variable amount of tasks per invoice

NOO!!!

Make a many-to-many tables between invoices and tasks, and make the constraint between this table and both the invoice and task table.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`invoices`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`invoices` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `date` DATETIME NULL ,
  `amount` DECIMAL(7,2) NULL ,
  `whatever` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tasks`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tasks` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `whatever` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`invoices_has_tasks`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`invoices_has_tasks` (
  `invoices_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `tasks_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoices_id`, `tasks_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_invoices_has_tasks_tasks1_idx` (`tasks_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_invoices_has_tasks_invoices_idx` (`invoices_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_invoices_has_tasks_invoices`
    FOREIGN KEY (`invoices_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`invoices` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_invoices_has_tasks_tasks1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tasks_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`tasks` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the invoice table

```
CREATE TABLE invoice (
    invoice_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

To create the tasks table use

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
    task_id INT, 
    invoice_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (invoice_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) 
        REFERENCES invoice(invoice_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

That is all you need

Comment: invoice table PK should be invoice_id, not id (I am sure a typo).  More importantly, tasks should be normalized and broken into two tables, one for the entity tasks and the second which links the task to the invoice (and if this is what you intended, then you should add a second FK in tasks linking table to the task entity table).

Comment: Typo, no.  As for opinion, I don't think it is just mine.

Comment: Any reason for not thinking so?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html this is where the original query came from, I just adopted it for his purpose... I think you seem to know more than the dev guide

Comment: It is not how you created the FK, but that tasks is not normalized. Per the OP (and what I would recommend), tasks were to be a separate table.  How you show it, a given task can only be associated with a single invoice and the information will need to be duplicated in each task table (i.e. not normalized).  I also don't typically recommend CASCADE, but I suppose that is only my opinion (but probably others).  If you look at the next example (product/customer) after the one you copied, it describes what I did but uses a compound key (either way works).